# Not able to use enum in mysql

Tags: mysql, enums

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CountryLanguage;  
CREATE TABLE CountryLanguage (  
  CountryCode CHAR(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
  Language CHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
  IsOfficial ENUM('True','False') NOT NUll default 'False',   
  Percentage FLOAT(4,1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0',  
  PRIMARY KEY  (CountryCode,Language)  
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO CountryLanguage VALUES ('AND','Spanish',0,44.6);
```

When I enter the insert statement it gives me an error:

> 'Data truncated for column IsOfficial'.

It only gives an error when I use 0 ,it works well for 1.

Answer (score 1):

your enum  is  IsOfficial ENUM('True','False')   ... then you should ue only the strin  'True' or 'False'  (not the boolean conceptually related)

```
INSERT INTO CountryLanguage VALUES ('AND','Spanish','False',44.6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the [`ENUM` type indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html) are not zero-based:

> ### Index Values for Enumeration Literals
>
> Each enumeration value has an index:
>
> - The elements listed in the column specification are assigned index numbers, **beginning with 1**.

Additionally, `0` has a special meaning:

> The index value of the empty string error value is 0. This means that you can use the following SELECT statement to find rows into which invalid ENUM values were assigned:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE enum_col=0;
> ```

If you go through the hassle of defining and maintaining an ENUM type you could just use the text labels. However, for a simple boolean column I would just use `TINYINT` and 0/1 values, maybe through the `TRUE` and `FALSE`constants:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CountryLanguage;  
CREATE TABLE CountryLanguage (  
  CountryCode CHAR(3) NOT NULL,  
  Language CHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
  IsOfficial TINYINT(1) NOT NULL default false,   
  Percentage FLOAT(4,1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0,  
  PRIMARY KEY (CountryCode, Language)  
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO CountryLanguage (CountryCode, Language, IsOfficial, Percentage)
VALUES ('AND', 'Spanish', false, 44.6);

INSERT INTO CountryLanguage (CountryCode, Language, IsOfficial, Percentage)
VALUES ('AND', 'Catalan ', true, 33);
```